# New numbered style without numbers in Microsoft Word 2016

Tags: microsoft-word

I'd like to create new style that would always format one sentence and by choosing that style, it would prepend static word to it.

I wanted to achieve this by new numbered style which inserts static word but Word won't let me create the style without actually numbering it and I don't want any numbers there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I did it in Word 2016:

1. On the **Home** tab, click **Multilevel list** > **Define new List Style**.
2. In the **Define New List Style** dialog box, click **Format** > **Numbering**.
3. In the **Modify Multilevel List** dialog box, in the **Number style for this level** field, select **(none)**.
4. In the **Enter formatting for number** field, enter the static text.
5. Click **Font**, and adjust the font properties for the static text, as required.
6. Adjust the settings under **Position** as required.
7. Click **More >>**.
8. In the **Link level to style** field, select the paragraph style that you want to automatically add the static text to.
9. Click **OK**.

For my example, I added the static text 'Note:', in bold, to Word's built-in **Block Text** paragraph style.

[image: Note paragraph]